# Is it possible to control the orientation of another app started through implicit intent?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, external-application

In my app, I have to show a video in Youtube. When the user press a button, I start this video through the following implicit intent, passing the url of the video in Youtube.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.video_url))));
```

This starts another app, like the Youtube app.

My doubut is: 
***Is it possible to make the youtube app play a video only in landscape or portrait orientation?***

Answer (score 0):

yes add permission on android manifeast

Comment: But the permission in manifest in only for setting the orientation of my app, isn't it? How this permission will affect another app, like the youtube app?